# update a file with the content of a variable, if need be, in bash

Tags: bash

In order to update some files only if their desired content has changed, I have been using this script:

```
updatefile()
{
  # First parameter is file name.
  # Second parameter is desired content.

  local FILENAME
  local DIRNAME
  local FILEALREADYMATCHING
  local CURRENTFILECONTENT

  if [ $# -ne 2 ] ; then
    return 99
  fi

  FILENAME=$(basename "$1")
  DIRNAME=$(dirname "$FILENAME")
  FILECONTENT="$2"

  mkdir -p "$DIRNAME"
  if [ -d "$DIRNAME" ] ; then
    FILEALREADYMATCHING=true
    if ! [ -f "$FILENAME" ] ; then
      FILEALREADYMATCHING=false
    else
      CURRENTFILECONTENT="$(IFS= cat "$FILENAME")X"
      CURRENTFILECONTENT=${CURRENTFILECONTENT%?}
      if [ "$CURRENTFILECONTENT" != "$FILECONTENT" ] ; then
        FILEALREADYMATCHING=false
      fi
    fi
    if [ "$FILEALREADYMATCHING" != "true" ] ; then
      printf '%s' "$2" > "$FILENAME"
    fi
  fi
}
```

But I found out that it carries on rewriting the file even when its current content is already matching the desired content. All the X appending and removing gymnastics did not help. Debug-printing the current and desired content shows no difference. What is wrong with the comparison I am using?

Alternatively, is there a standard way of changing a file's content without wearing off the drive? If it matters, I am using the most recent version of Bash on OpenWRT, but the needless overwriting also occurs on Debian testing, amd64.

Comment: what are you passing in `$2`? What is your actual requirement? comparing contents of two files? Can you elaborate more with some more content?

Comment: Actually, the script should work perfectly; I tested it. Maybe it has to do with how you deploy it? How do you do that? As part of a larger script that calls the function as `uptatefile $1 $2`? As a definition in `~/.bashrc` or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code actually works perfectly fine when I tried it, however;

## This may be where it's falling apart:

```
  FILENAME=$(basename "$1")         # <-- Path is REMOVED here 
  DIRNAME=$(dirname "$FILENAME")    # <-- No point running, path is already gone
  FILECONTENT="$2"
```

- Say i have a file: `/tmp/testfile`
- If i run `basename /tmp/testfile` I get: `testfile`
- **If I then run `dirname testfile`** it doesn't magically find the original path again.

**Reverse the order of argument assignment and try again:**

```
DIRNAME=$(dirname "$1")           # <-- No point running, path is already gone      
FILENAME=$(basename "$1")         # <-- Path is REMOVED here 
FILECONTENT="$2"
```

---

#### Sidenote

Why don't you add some debug code to it to see where it's falling apart.

I find this sometimes help when `bash -x` is just a bit busy

```
#!/bin/bash

  # First parameter is file name.
  # Second parameter is desired content.

decho () {

if [ "$debug" == "1" ]; then
echo "$@"
return
fi

}


updatefile () {
  local FILENAME
  local DIRNAME
  local FILEALREADYMATCHING
  local CURRENTFILECONTENT

  if [ $# -ne 2 ] ; then
    decho returning                                    #echo if debug=1
    return 99
  fi

  FILENAME=$(basename "$1")
  DIRNAME=$(dirname "$FILENAME")
  FILECONTENT="$2"

  mkdir -p "$DIRNAME"
  if [ -d "$DIRNAME" ] ; then
    FILEALREADYMATCHING=true
    if ! [ -f "$FILENAME" ] ; then
      FILEALREADYMATCHING=false
      decho "file doesn't exist"                       #echo if debug=1
    else
      CURRENTFILECONTENT="$(IFS= cat "$FILENAME")X"
      CURRENTFILECONTENT=${CURRENTFILECONTENT%?}
      decho "file exists"                              #echo if debug=1

      if [ "$CURRENTFILECONTENT" != "$FILECONTENT" ] ; then
        decho "content is different"                   #echo if debug=1
        FILEALREADYMATCHING=false
      fi
    fi
    if [ "$FILEALREADYMATCHING" != "true" ] ; then
       decho "file doesnt match, making it match now"  #echo if debug=1
       decho "file is $FILENAME by the way"            #echo if debug=1
      printf '%s' "$2" > "$FILENAME"
    fi
  fi
}


updatefile "$1" "$2"
```

So then, instead of invoking the script like this:

```
./script filename "Content"
```

invoke it like this:

```
debug=1 ./script filename "Content"
```

Comment: Thank you. I think the whole function is failing because dirname returns a dot. The test is therefore looking for a file with the right name, but in the wrong directory. It can't find the old version of the file, so it creates a new version, thankfully in the right place.

I do have debug output and tests, but I was always testing with a file in the same directory as the test script.